# Sort comma separated list Alphabetically PHP

Tags: php

I have the data in a PHP variable in a comma separated list. Here is the data (some part of it to save space)

```
$xyz="Europe, France, Italy, Spain, UK, US,Nordic, West Europe, Belgium, Luxembourg, Netherlands, Sweden,US,Asia, Europe, Israel, North America, India,North America, , China, Hong Kong,West North Central, West South Central,UK,East South Central,Middle Atlantic, Greater China, Malaysia, Singapore, Taiwan, Middle Atlantic, Global, Australasia, Central and East Europe";
```

I want to sort this alphabetically. Currently I do this manually but it is tedious Is there any easier way to do this?

Kind regards,
Ahmar

Comment: "easier way" than what? How are you currently attempting to do it? Perhaps there is a simple fix to what you've done so far.

Comment: and how you want the result back?

Comment: In ascending or descending order alphabetically

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am pasting you a snippet what it is doing:

1. Splicing string
2. Remove blank spaces on each element
3. Remove empty elements
4. Sorting array
5. Printing the result

I hope it is usefull for you

```
<?php
$xyz = "Europe, France, Italy, Spain, UK, US,Nordic, West Europe, Belgium, Luxembourg, Netherlands, Sweden,US,Asia, Europe, Israel, North America, India,North America, , China, Hong Kong,West North Central, West South Central,UK,East South Central,Middle Atlantic, Greater China, Malaysia, Singapore, Taiwan, Middle Atlantic, Global, Australasia, Central and East Europe";
$array = array_filter(array_map('trim', explode(',', $xyz)));
asort($array);
$array = implode(', ', $array);
print_r($array);
```

Comment: `asort` doesn't just sort the array, it maintains key association.  To just "sort the array" you might you `sort($array)`.

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
$xyz="Europe, France, Italy, Spain, UK, US,Nordic, West Europe, Belgium, Luxembourg, Netherlands, Sweden,US,Asia, Europe, Israel, North America, India,North America, , China, Hong Kong,West North Central, West South Central,UK,East South Central,Middle Atlantic, Greater China, Malaysia, Singapore, Taiwan, Middle Atlantic, Global, Australasia, Central and East Europe";

$arr = explode(',', $xyz);
asort($arr);
print_r($arr);
```

Comment: `explode` will cause issues with the inconsistent spaces.  Try `preg_split('/,\s*/')` instead.

Answer (score 3):

```
// break apart the string at each comma
$parts = explode(',',$xyz);

// create an array
$array = array();

// loop through $parts and put each country into the new array
foreach($parts as $part) {
    array_push($array,$part);
}

// sort the array alphabetically
asort($array);

print_r($array);
```

Comment: `$array = array(); foreach($parts as $part) { array_push($array,$part); }` is pointless.

Answer (score 2):

use `explode`:

```
$xyz_arr = explode(',', $xyz);
sort($xyz_arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

My answer is partially based off of @Carlos answer but with a few tweaks here-and-there, and wrapped into a reusable function. It should be more than capable of getting the job done, right!

```
/* A global function to sort a [STRING] comma-delimited list both alphabetically, and numerically, and then return the sorted [STRING] list back to the function caller. [BEGIN] */

if (!function_exists('sortCommaDelimitedListStr'))
    {
        function sortCommaDelimitedListStr($var)
            {
                $arr = array_filter(array_map('trim', explode(',', $var)));
                sort($arr);
                $arr = implode(', ', $arr);
                return $arr;
            };
    };

/* A global function to sort a [STRING] comma-delimited list both alphabetically, and numerically, and then return the sorted [STRING] list back to the function caller. [END] */
```

To use, simply call the function like so:

```
$xyz = "Europe, France, Italy, Spain, UK, US,Nordic, West Europe, Belgium, Luxembourg, Netherlands, Sweden,US,Asia, Europe, Israel, North America, India,North America, , China, Hong Kong,West North Central, West South Central,UK,East South Central,Middle Atlantic, Greater China, Malaysia, Singapore, Taiwan, Middle Atlantic, Global, Australasia, Central and East Europe";

$xyz = sortCommaDelimitedListStr($xyz);
```

Answer (score 0):

1. First explode the string on comma with explode function.
2. Remove white space with array_map() function.
3. Sort the array in ascending order with asort() function.
4. Then convert array into string with implode().

```
$xyz="Europe, France, Italy, Spain, UK, US,Nordic, West Europe, Belgium, Luxembourg, Netherlands, Sweden,US,Asia, Europe, Israel, North America, India,North America, , China, Hong Kong,West North Central, West South Central,UK,East South Central,Middle Atlantic, Greater China, Malaysia, Singapore, Taiwan, Middle Atlantic, Global, Australasia, Central and East Europe";
```

$xyz = explode(',',$xyz);
$trimSpaces = array_map('trim',$xyz);
asort($trimSpaces);
$xyz = implode(',',$trimSpaces);
print_r($xyz);

Comment: Please explain step by step your solution so it is clear to everyone reading it.

Comment: i have added explanation please review.